# SKAction moves sprite in front of others

Tags: ios, sprite-kit, skspritenode, z-order, skaction

I am trying to animate one of my sprites. The problem is while running SKAction this sprite comes in front of all other sprites. It won't work as I expected to.

I am running this function for animating my sprite when user presses a button to move.

```
 -(void)RightTurn
 {
     [sprite1 removeAllActions];

         turn = [SKAction repeatAction:[SKAction animateWithTextures:@[texture1, texture2, texture3] timePerFrame:0.05] count:1];
     [sprite1 runAction:turn];
```

}

All textures are declared when loading scene. When I release a button, I am removing all actions, at this time sprite goes back where it belongs. So I am pretty sure that this is SKAaction problem. I couldn't find similar problem somewhere else so anyone any idea?

Comment: Did you by chance create the project using the Game template in Xcode?

Comment: @MobileBen i don't remember. maybe yes? why?

Comment: Do you have GameScene and GameViewController? And you didn't create them manually?

Comment: @MobileBen true that. So what's the problem?

Comment: Take a look at GameViewController.m and see if this line exists `skView.ignoresSiblingOrder = YES;`. If so, try setting it to NO and see if that works.

Comment: @MobileBen thanks! I missed that.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the z position of the sprite. Set the spriteObject.zPosition lesser then the z position  of other sprites. That will solve your problem.